# Pass Parameters to ClickOnce Using ShellExecute

Tags: c#, clickonce

I was attempting to use this [Blog](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/03/21/how-to-pass-arguments-to-an-offline-clickonce-application/) to pass an argument to an offline click-once application.  Near the bottom of the blog there are example programs to download.  I downloaded and published the program "TestRunningWithArgs" the C# version.

Now I am trying to pass an argument to the application which is not working.  It keeps saying no "No arguments passed in".

I am trying to use the following code to pass an argument:

`shellexecute("File Path\My Applicaiton.application","MyArgument")`

This code runs the application but the sample application states it did not receive an argument.  The language is visual basic (maybe 4 or 6?).

The code below works and allows internet explorer to run and a specific file be opened from sharepoint and I was wondering if there is a difference that I am missing.

`shellexecute("C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe",FileLocation)`

The only one I see is that the click once is a .application file vs a .exe and is there a way to get this to work?

**Below is the code for the click once application, just copied from the supplied example program on the blog**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    GetArgsToShow();
}

/// Get the arguments and show them on the screen.
private void GetArgsToShow()
{
    //   Get the ActivationArguments from the SetupInformation property of the domain.
    string[] activationData = 
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData;

    if (activationData != null && activationData.Length > 0)
    {
        //querystring starts with ?; file association starts with "file:"
        if (activationData.Length == 1 && activationData[0].Substring(0, 1) == "?")
        {
            ProcessQueryString(activationData);
        }
        else if (activationData.Length == 1 && activationData[0].Length >= 5 && activationData[0].Substring(0,5).ToLower() == @"file:")
        {
            ProcessFileAssociation(activationData);
        }
        else 
        {
            ProcessCSVParameters(activationData);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (activationData == null)
        {
            lstArgs.Items.Add("No arguments passed in.");
        }
        else
        {
            lstArgs.Items.Add(String.Format("Number of args = {0}", activationData.Length));
        }
    }

}

/// Convert a query string into Name/Value pairs and process it.
private void ProcessQueryString(string[] activationData)
{
    NameValueCollection nvc = 
      System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(activationData[0]);

    //Get all the keys in the collection, then pull the values for each of them.
    //I'm only passing each key once, with one value.
    string[] theKeys = nvc.AllKeys;
    foreach (string theKey in theKeys)
    {
        string[] theValue = nvc.GetValues(theKey);
        lstArgs.Items.Add(string.Format("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", theKey, theValue[0]));
    }                   
}

/// Process what you would get if you set up a file association, 
/// and the user double-clicked on one of the associated file.
private void ProcessFileAssociation(string[] activationData)
{
    //This is what you get when you set up a file association and the user double-clicks 
    //  on an associated file. 
    Uri uri = new Uri(activationData[0]);
    lstArgs.Items.Add(uri.LocalPath.ToString());
}

/// Process a comma-delimited string of values. Not: can't have spaces or double-quotes in the string,
/// it will only read the first argument.
private void ProcessCSVParameters(string[] activationData)
{
    //I have to say here that I've only ever seen 1 entry passed in activationData,
    //  but I'm checking for multiples just in case. 
    //This takes each entry and splits it by comma and separates them into separate entries.

    char[] myComma = { ',' };

    foreach (string arg in activationData)
    {
        string[] myList = activationData[0].Split(myComma, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string oneItem in myList)
            lstArgs.Items.Add(oneItem);
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT**
Well I tried accessing the .exe located in "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\5G9CGPWV.6O3\X7YPB07N.2Q2\test..tion_0000000000000000_0001.0000_03232931d88a66c9\" which did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Found the file you have to call to send an argument.

`shellexecute("C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\(Publisher Name)\My Application.appref-ms", Arguement)`

The publisher name is specified in visual studio Publish Tab, options and then Publisher Name.  This is also the Start Menu Folder where your program can be launched from.